# How do I push a view controller in one case, but present it modally in another?

Tags: swift, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have a view controller (VC3) that I want to *push* if accessed via one screen (VC1), but present it *modally* if accessed from a different screen (VC2). The destination view controller (VC3) is on its own storyboard and is embedded in a `UINavigationController`(which I believe is pretty important here).

In `prepare(for segue)` on VC1 I have this:

```
 if let nav = segue.destination as? UINavigationController {
     let destinationViewController = nav.topViewController as! LiftsViewController
     destinationViewController.delegate = self
   }
```

This presents the destination view controller (VC3) modally, which is what I want.

From VC2, the view controller (VC3) will be accessed by tapping on a cell in a table view so I want it *pushed*. But in `prepare(for segue)` on VC2 I have the same code as above because, well, I'm segueing to the same view controller which is in the `UINavigationController`.

I've looked at quite a few threads that address pushing vcs or presenting them modally, but can't find anything that answers how to do both with the same vc.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't push a `NavigationController` into another `NavigationController`

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini, but that doesn't actually help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this scenario let's not use the segue and push/present your VC's programmatically.

```
let vc3 = (UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LiftsViewController") as? LiftsViewController)!
vc3.delegate = self
```

now push:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc3, animated: true)
```

or present:

```
self.presentViewController(vc3, animated: true, completion: nil)
```